# Using ROS to read images over TCP/IP

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to ROS( been through the turtlesim tutorials). I am working on reading images from an image server over a TCP/IP connection using ROS. I havent written my first code yet. Can any one tell me as to how I should proceed with this task?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9969/using-ros-to-read-images-over-tcp/ip/) by [Subodh](https://answers.ros.org/users/541/subodh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-16**:
That's a very broad question. I'd suggest asking something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have not done this myself, but I have seen some mentions of IP cameras.

You may want to have a look at this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/879/is-there-any-package-for-ip-camera).  This camera node may also be of interest: http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=axis_camera

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2011-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1